# Change dataframe values R using different column name provided?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, position, assign

I have the following data frame:

```
     Column1 Default_Val
1          A           2
2          B           2
3          C           2
4          D           2
5          E           2
...
colnames: "Column1" "Default_Val"
rownames: "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"
```

This data frame is part of my function and this function changes the default values according to some if's.

I want to generalize the assignment process because I want to support different column names of this data frame.

Please advise how can I change the default value without being dependent of column names?

Here is what I did so far:

```
df[Column1 == "A","Default_Val"]
[1] 2
df[Column1 == "A","Default_Val"] = 2
df[Column1 == "A","Default_Val"]
[1] 1
```

I want something generalized like:

```
t <- colnames(df)
df[t[1] == "A", t[2]] = 7
```

For some reason it doesn't work (each time this happens I love Python more :)).

Please advise.

Comment: Did you try ```colnames(df)```

Comment: Sure, it doesn't work. It's a typo I will edit the question. 
But if you have a smart solution for my problem it would be great. In Python it's piece of cake, R is as always making trouble.

Comment: If i understood right, you want to assign a value based on the column index not the column name, right?

Comment: You get a dataframe of 2 columns, you don't know the column names, I want to go to the first column and ask: give me the element called "A" for example, and change it's value in the second column.
I know that first column is character/strings and second is numeric.
Hope it helps you to help me.

Comment: No need to hate on `R` just because you don't understand the syntax. Try `df[df[,1] == "A", 2] <- 3` to change the value(s) of elements whose value in column 1 is `"A"` to 3 in column 2.

Comment: In Python it's much more easier but each of us likes different languages more or less and it's ok.
I will try it @LAP, thank you!
I have solved it in a different way, just assigned rownames and deleted the column1 for duplicate. What do you think?

Comment: It is usually bad form to use rownames in a data.frame, but you do you.

Comment: @LAP May I ask why?

Comment: I'd say because it is unnecessary, and it is usually easier to index cells by information given in columns. In this case, it may not make a difference, although I'm not sure if referring to `rownames` instead of a column index might perform less well on big data chunks. That would probably require benchmarking, and if your data is small (below ~ 10k rows), you're probably fine.

Comment: @LAP thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be straightforward. Please check if this solves your problem.

```
> df
  Column1 Default_val
1       A           1
2       B           3
3       A           4
4       C           1
5       D           4
> df[2][df[1] == 'A'] = 3
> df
  Column1 Default_val
1       A           3
2       B           3
3       A           3
4       C           1
5       D           4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try it!